# iTunes cannot read the contents of the iPad “foo”.

Tags: ios

When connecting my iPad and launching iTunes get the error message 'iTunes cannot read the contents of the iPad “foo”. 
I then have the option to eject or restore my iPad.

I am running the latest iOS 8.1.2 and latest iTunes 12.0.1.26 on OSX 10.10 Yosemite.

The frustrating thing is that this is the second time I received this message in a week, and JUST restored my iPad, losing data in the process!

It was syncing fine for a couple days AFTER the restore, but am getting this message again.
WTF! I don't want to restore again....can anyone point to a possible solution?

Comment: ok answering my own question but came across a youtube vid that suggests that I download an app called i-funbox http://www.i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/

Answer (score 1):

https://discussions.apple.com/message/17023223

Use ifunbox or iTools and go to
raw files
var
mobile
media
itunes control

delete your music folder (it will resync just fine later)

then go to the itunes folder next to it
delete "itunes cdb", and "itunes control" and if you have "itunesdb" delete that too
close ifunbox then reopen itunes.
I've done this fix a few times.